# ASP.NET version for virtual directory changes when IIS is restarted

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have a .NET 1.1 app in its own virtual directory.  I set it to .NET 1.1 in the asp.net version tab.

Everytime I restart IIS, the asp.net version gets changed to .NET 2.0.

Can someone please explain why it is doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before but I cannot recall the exact sequence of events that causes it.  I believe it has to do with having applications with .Net 1.1 and 2.0 in the same app pool.  You cannot run applications with .Net 1.1 and 2.0 in the same app pool.  I am just speculating, but your main IIS website is probably set to .Net 2.0 which is then pushing down to your virtual directory when you restart IIS (or restart the app pool).

Make sure your virtual directory is set to be an application in IIS and then move it to it's own app pool or an app pool that contains only .Net 1.1 applications.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use ASP.NET 1.1? Let it use 2.0 or higher. ASP.NET 1.1 is now so old, I cannot imagine any advantage in attempting to force this.